# installing EE on web server in sub-directory...URLs...ugh

Tags: url, ee3

I'm new to expression engine and I run into this aggravating problem EVERY time I install EE. Whenever I upload my templates, my URLS break almost everytime. The only way to fix it is to go in an manuelly tag every image IMAGE/CSS/JS URL with {base_site} and then ensure my folders are all on the base of the my site/sub-folder. Is there any other way to ensure my URLs won't break at upload other than what I just said? It's just so time-consuming to have to do it all manuelly? Once again, this is in a sub-direction (i.e. website.com/_development_sites/mysite).

See the below code for an example. Do I really have to insert the {base_url} for all my JS/CSS files and IMAGE tags and image links in order for them to work? Isn't there a faster work around so I don't have to spend so much time customizing my HTML template before uploading?

Any ideas?

`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{base_url}css/overrides.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{base_url}css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`
```

Comment: Can you clarify with some before/after code. Your question isn't overly clear.

Comment: I added more code to be clear, sorry for the lack of example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but I'll at least give a suggestions moving forward (it is probably too long for a comment). One reason I'm not sure if it answers your questions is because your `.htaccess` rules could handle this, but I wouldn't recommend that route.

If you install EE in a sub-directory (say `http://www.site.com/ee-site/`), you should be setting your site `Default Base URL` to `http://www.site.com/ee-site/`. Then, when you **generate** new templates, always use the `{site_url}` tag in the beginning of your links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}css/overrides.css" type="text/css" />
```

This is a best (or at least better) practice. This way, say you have three copies of a website that look like this:

```
Development site : Default Base URL : http://www.site.com/development/
Staging site     : Default Base URL : http://www.site.com/staging/
Production site  : Default Base URL : http://www.site.com/
```

You can work on a template in your development site, and as long as you always use your `{site_url}` tag in the beginning of your `href` and `src` parameters, you can copy that template between sites freely and it will automatically work.

You could even change domain from say `http://www.site.com` to `http://www.new-site.com` and as long as you set each `Default Base URL` for each site correctly, you'll be all set.

Comment: Great, that helps alot. Why do you advise against using the .htaccess file for doing this same thing though? Wouldn't that be faster?

Comment: It adds a level of complexity that lives outside of the framework and lives more in the "DevOps" role domain (server provisioning and deployment). You'd have to have different versions of your `.htaccess` file for each site, and if you need to change one, you'd need to change three. This eliminates that with essentially a CMS environment setting you set once and leave alone.

Comment: Note that what I said isn't exactly true; you can manage environments and ENV variables in at your PHP server level so you wouldn't actually need three different `.htaccess` files... but again, now you're diving deeper outside of the CMS for something you can solve inside.